Is there a concise description of the $\infty$-category $\mathrm{Mod}_A^\mathcal{O}(\mathcal{C})$ of modules over an algebra over an $\infty$-operad?
[Cross-posted to this MO question.]
In Higher Algebra, Section 3.3 Lurie constructs the $\infty$-operads $\newcommand{\Mod}{\mathrm{Mod}}\newcommand{\cO}{\mathcal{O}}\newcommand{\cC}{\mathcal{C}}\Mod^{\cO}(\cC)^\otimes$ and $\Mod_A^{\cO}(\cC)^\otimes$ for $\cO^\otimes$ a unital $\infty$-operad, $\cC^\otimes \to \cO^\otimes$ a fibration of (generalized) $\infty$-operads, and $\newcommand{\Alg}{\mathrm{Alg}} A \in \Alg_{/ \cO}(\cC)$ an algebra object. The construction is rather involved: First he constructs a simplicial set $\widetilde{\Mod}^{\cO}(\cC)^\otimes$ together with a map $q\colon \widetilde{\Mod}^{\cO}(\cC)^\otimes \to \cO^\otimes$ such that for all maps of simplicial sets $X \to \cO^\otimes$ there is a canonical bijection
$$\newcommand{\Fun}{\mathrm{Fun}} 
  \Fun_{\cO^\otimes}(X, \widetilde{\Mod}^{\cO}(\cC)^\otimes) \cong \Fun_{\Fun(\{1\}, \cO^\otimes)}(X \times_{\Fun(\{0\}, \cO^\otimes)} \mathcal{K}_{\cO}, \cC^\otimes)
$$
where $\mathcal{K}_{\cO} \subseteq \Fun(\Delta^1, \cO^\otimes)$ is the full subcategory of semi-inert morphisms in $\cO^\otimes$. He then picks out the full simplicial subset $\overline{\Mod}^{\cO}(\cC)^\otimes \subseteq \widetilde{\Mod}^{\cO}(\cC)^\otimes$ spanned by all vertices $\bar{v}$ such that $\bar{v}$ determines a functor
$$
    \{v\} \times_{\cO^\otimes} \mathcal{K}_{\cO} \to \cC^\otimes
$$
which carries inert morphisms to inert morphisms (here a morphism in $\mathcal{K}_{\cO}$ are inert if its image under the evaluation maps $e_0, e_1\colon \mathcal{K}_{\cO} \to \cO^\otimes$ at the vertices of $\Delta^1$ is inert).
This is followed by around a page of observations, a similar definition for algebras, and finally the definition we care about: In the setting of the first sentence of this question, he defines
$$
    \Mod^{\cO}(\cC)^\otimes := \overline{\Mod}^{\cO}(\cC)^\otimes \times_{{}^\mathrm{p} \Alg_{/ \cO}(\cC)}(\cO^\otimes \times \Alg_{/ \cO}(\cC))
$$
and further
$$
    \Mod^{\cO}_A(\cC)^\otimes := \Mod^{\cO}(\cC)^\otimes \times_{\Alg_{/ \cO}(\cC)} \{A\}
$$
(I won't describe all maps and constructions involved for brevity's sake).
This definition is, to put it mildly, a bit convoluted. In the introductory paragraph to the section, however, Lurie states that "the construction of $\Mod_A^{\cO}(\cC)^\otimes$ as a simplicial set with a map to $N(\mathrm{Fin}_*)$ is fairly straightforward; the bulk of our work will be in proving that $\Mod^\cO_A(\cC)^\otimes$ is actually an $\infty$-operad." I am thus led to wonder what the "straightforward construction" of $\Mod^\cO_A(\cC)^\otimes$ is supposed to be: Am I to "identify" $\Mod^\cO(\cC)^\otimes$ with $\overline{\Mod}^{\cO}(\cC)^\otimes$? After all, the map $\cO^\otimes \times \Alg_{/ \cO}(\cC) \to {}^\mathrm{p} \Alg_{/ \cO}(\cC)$ I am pulling back along in the definition of the former is a categorical equivalence, so I have a categorical equivalence $\Mod^\cO(\cC)^\otimes \to \overline{\Mod}^{\cO}(\cC)^\otimes$. Even so, the construction of $\overline{\Mod}^{\cO}(\cC)^\otimes$ in and of itself is a little complicated in its own right and not exactly pretty.
My question, thus: Assuming that I don't care about proving that $\Mod^\cO(\cC)^\otimes$ is an $\infty$-operad (or even an $\infty$-category), is there a construction of it that is simpler and/or more concise than the one of $\overline{\Mod}^\cO(\cC)^\otimes$ presented in Higher Algebra, possibly under additional simplifying assumptions?
(Context: I am giving a talk about $\infty$-operads in which I am supposed to introduce, among other things, modules. Giving the full definition would eat a chunk of my time that I already don't have, and any amount of simplification would probably aid understanding in my audience.)

N.b. I have looked at various other sources, e.g. Gepner's An Introduction to Higher Categorical Algebra or Hebestreit's Algebraic and Hermitian $K$-Theory Notes but it seems like everyone either avoids modules altogether or only treats the special case of left/right modules over monoids or modules over commutative monoids.

I thought a bit about it, and for a general coherent $\infty$-operad $\mathcal{O}$ I don't think you will find a simpler description if you require to actually specify all coherences, or at least within the framework of this way of defining $\infty$-operads. Lurie's definition may look weird at first, but if you play around with some examples (e.g. $\mathcal{O}$ being the commutative operad), then you'll see what Lurie is doing is sort of the least painful way of generalizing what happens in those examples.

It may be easier if you don't want to specify the $\infty$-operad of $A$-modules over $\mathcal{C}$, but only the underlying $\infty$-category. In this case, there should be an $\infty$-operad $\mathrm{Mod}^\mathcal{O}$ whose algebras in $\mathcal{C}$ are the $\infty$-category of $\mathcal{O}$-algebras $A$ together with an $A$-module $M$. However, the simplest way to describe this $\infty$-operad likely still uses the notion of semi-inert morphisms.
